# how to find a point that is nearest to the most points when we have some Blocks in between! ( in array 2D - Snake Game)

Tags: algorithm, grid, distance, path-finding

I'm working on a snake game (Nibbles in Linux) that is played on a 60*60 field, with four snakes competing for an apple which is randomly placed.

I've implemented the movement of my snake with the A* (A star) Algorithm.

My problem is this: When I'm not the nearest snake to the apple, I don't want to go to get the apple, because my chance to get it is lower than at least one snake, so I want to look for a place that I *hope* at the next place that an apple is generated , Then I'll be the nearest snake to that apple. I mean that  I'm looking for a place which is nearest to the maximum number of potential locations.

Please suggest any good way or any algorithm that can help me to find this place.

Here is an image of the game.  The red points are the snakes' heads.

[image: a snapshot of SnakeGame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested some ways and Finally I decided to use this way:

I think the best way is to make a 2D array with size:60*60 , then for each node(x) of the array, calculate how many nodes of the field-which are walkable!(not block), is this node(x) nearest to.

then the answer will be The maximum amount, then I set this node the goal.

but because I must find the next move in less than 0.1sec and to do this work, there is 4 loops of size:60, (60^4) and when I found it, A* algorithm will be run too , this work would never be done in less than 0.1 sec.

So , since the Snake can't move Diagonally and it goes just: up,down,right,left, I decided not to check all the nodes,Since in each cycle(0.1sec) , I can just move 1 unit, I decided to check just 4 nodes(up,down,left,right) and move to a node which It's amount is Max.

now it's working almost right. ;)

Comment: Seems to be a good solution, but I didn't think about your solution bugs, ofcourse if you think this is better than other answers, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are nearest to apple you should walk to get it but if you are far apart from apple your best chance is walking in a middle of map, you should find strategy to how to occupy the middle of map.

You can divide your map to four zooms (clockwise), upper left, upper right, bottom right and bottom left (1,2,3,4). We check this between two snakes: If apple currently is in zoom 1 (assume center for average) and you are in center of map, your opponent can be in zooms 1,2,3,4 (again assume it's in the center of this zooms to take average in simpler way) if it's in zoom 1 it has better chance (1-0) if it's in zoom 2 or 4, your distance is sqrt(2)/2 and your opponent distance is 1, so you are nearest, and finally if your opponent is in zoom 3 your distance is sqrt(2)/2 and your opponent distance is sqrt(2), so in 3 cases with one oppnent you have better chance.

But because your shape has some blocks, you should calculate center position in other way, in fact, for each point in your grid calculate its distance to all other points. this will take 60^2 * 60^2 which can be done fast. and find cells with minimum total sums(you can select best 10 cells), this cells can be your centers, everytime you should move from one center to another (except when you are nearest to apple or your snake eats apple and wants comback to nearest centers) .

Comment: again, this isn't what is asked for.  if there is one competitor on the extreme left, then the best place to be is just to the right of them.  that gives you an advantage over the competitor for any apple not in the first two columns.  your solution doesn't do as well as this.

Comment: sorry - see my other comment here.  if you edit this answer (anything, just to get around stackoverflow's restrictions) i'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already implemented A*, after you generate your map, you could use A* to create a map of values for each cell based on the total cost from each cell to visit every other cell.  If you generate this after you've placed your blocks, then your weighted map will account for their presence.

To generate this, off the top of my head, I would say you could start from each cell, and assign it one point for each cell it can visit in one turn.  For example, a cell in the corner would get two points for the first move, because it can only access two other cells.  It would get five points for the second turn, because it can access five cells in two moves.  Repeat until you've visited all the other squares, and then you have the score for that square.

From that point, if an apple appears and your snake is not the closest to it, your snake could head for the highest weighted cell, which you've calculated beforehand.

Edit:  Please see comments below for a more advantageous solution.

Comment: not what is asked for, though, is it?  what is asked for depends on the positions of the other snakes.

Comment: @andrewcooke He's looking for the place that closest to all other places.  That's where he wants to head if he is not the closest to a current apple, in anticipation of being faster to the next.

Comment: i don't think so.  i think the optimal place is closer to more places than any other snake.  there's no point in being close to lots of places if the other snakes are closer.

Comment: actually, re-reading the q you may be right (in which case they are not asking the best possible question, but that's the questioner's problem).  if you edit your answer (to unlock my vote) then i'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @andrewcooke Done.  You should also offer your answer, which though it may not be exactly what's being asked for, is a better answer to the core of the problem.

Comment: i don't see an efficient way to calculate it, unfortunately.

Comment: @andrewcooke ,K.G

thanks for your comments, lets say again, I'm looking for a place that in my current situation, the nodes which I'm nearest to is Max for me.

this amount can be lower than the amount of Other's Snake, I mean it is probable that another Snake be the Nearest to more Places, I am just looking for a place which this amount is Max for me,So i've tried my best ;)

Comment: @K.G. ,andrewcooke... I think finding an optimal soloution is not easy, and you'd better know that I must find the next move  in less than 0.1 sec ... So if you have a solution, even it's not optimal, I'll be glad to know ... here is a simple example: the coordination of the next move is (60-avgX , 60-avgY) where 60 is the height and width of the field and 'avgX' , 'avgY' are the average coordination of other Snake's heads.

Answer (score 0):

Nearest to the maximum number of locations is the center as others have stated.  Nearer to the  maximum number of locations than the other snakes is a much, different and harder questions.  In that case, I would A* the head of each snake to see who has the most squares under control.  That's the base score.  Next, as I'm drawing a blank, I'd Monte Carlo a random set of points around the map and choose the point that gave the highest score as a destination.  If you had the processing power, you could try every point on the grid and choose the best as K.G. suggested, but that could get pretty intense.

The true test is when you find your point, figure out how far in the future it takes you to get there, and running some AI for the other snakes to see if they will intercept you.  You start getting into plys like chess. :)

Comment: +1 for measuring A* from the snake's heads.  This incorporates some of andrew cooke's concerns about optimizing your target area for your opponents, and some of Saeed Amiri's ideas in zoning.  I'd like to see a video of this algorithm being run!